# GMP Asignar valores a un arreglo

Tags: c

Como dice el titulo, utilizando GMP primero quiero asignar todos los valores a 1 del arreglo y luego asignar solo los dos primeros valores del arreglo a 0

```
    mpz_t *array;

    array = (mpz_t *)malloc((mpz_get_ui(n)+1)*sizeof(mpz_t));


    for (i = 0; mpz_cmp_ui(n, i) == 0 || mpz_cmp_ui(n, i) == 1; i++){ 
        mpz_set_ui(array[i], 1);
    }

    mpz_set_ui(array[0], 0);
    mpz_set_ui(array[1], 0);
```

La idea del for es que sea mientras i <= n por eso las dos comparaciones con `mpz_cmp`

Eso es lo que tengo en mente pero  `||` no me funciona y al parecer `mpz_set_ui` tampoco me funciona

Answer (score 0):

El operador || no es válido en C. En su lugar, debería usar el operador || para hacer una comparación lógica "o" entre las dos comparaciones con mpz_cmp_ui.

Además, debería cambiar la comparación en el cuerpo del ciclo for para que sea mpz_cmp_ui(n, i) >= 0 en lugar de mpz_cmp_ui(n, i) == 0 || mpz_cmp_ui(n, i) == 1. Esto asegurará que el ciclo se ejecute mientras i sea menor o igual que n.

Por último, la función mpz_set_ui debería funcionar correctamente si se usa de la manera en la que lo está haciendo. Si sigue teniendo problemas, asegúrese de que array[i] esté inicializado con mpz_init_set_ui antes de intentar asignarle un valor con mpz_set_ui.

El código debería verse algo así:

```
mpz_t *array;

array = (mpz_t *)malloc((mpz_get_ui(n)+1)*sizeof(mpz_t));

for (i = 0; mpz_cmp_ui(n, i) >= 0; i++){ 
    mpz_init_set_ui(array[i], 1);
}

mpz_set_ui(array[0], 0);
mpz_set_ui(array[1], 0);
```

Comment: ¿Por que el cambio en la comparación asegura que el código se ejecute?

Comment: Usar chatGPT está prohibido en [es.so], además, usar chatGPT sin citar la fuente es considerado [Plagio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagio). Relacionado: [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes), [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). Tu cuenta puede ser suspendida por este motivo.